# socket.io is pending on node.js html client side

Tags: html, node.js, socket.io

my server side code is

```
app.get('/', function (req, res) {
     
 

  io.on('connection', function(socket) {
    socket.emit('announcements', { message: 'A new user has joined!' });
  });



//res.send.json(data);
    res.redirect("kroki.html");
  

  });
```

my client side code is

```
 <script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/socket.io/2.3.0/socket.io.js"></script>



        <script>
          var socket = io.connect('/');
           socket.on('connection', function(data) {
               console.log('Got announcement:', data.message);
         
       
           });
         </script>
```

But I got an error it said that socket.io is pending .it hasn't any console message

Where is my mistake? Thank you for your helps

Comment: `socket.on('connection',...)` should be `socket.on('announcements',...)`

Comment: move `io.on(...)` outside your route handler

Comment: thank you.I have solved my problem